# Update datatable row with its row index vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, datatable

I have a DataTable with column `DisplayOrder`. It maintains incremented values by 1 per Entity Column. In few scenarios this increment will disturb. Now I need to update the DataTable to maintain the `DisplayOrder` column value by 1.

I have tried following code. but it updates all rows by 1.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

dtCustomers.Select("EntityID =" & EntityID).ToList().ForEach(Function(r) InlineAssignHelper(r("DisplayOrder"), i))
```

Comment: Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Can you explain where this code is wrong and add the code for InlineAssignHelper?

Comment: using above code all row values of "DisplayOrder" are changed to 1

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code of InlineAssignHelper. Did you try my answer below?

Comment: Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function

Comment: Yes we can do it with the answer mentioned below. But i'm trying to do it in foreach loop. Anyway i have opted your answer because i have found that in current approach i cannot increment value.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your InlineAssignHelper takes the second parameter and tries to set the value for the column DisplayOrder. But as you have written this code that is not possible because you pass the VALUE of the column DisplayOrder for the current row and not the row itself. Moreover you need to increment the value of i otherwise you set always the value zero fixed outside the call to DisplayOrder.

For all this reasons (and also for more readability) I recommend to leave the ForEach list extension and use a traditional loop

```
Dim rows = dtCustomers.Select("EntityID =" & EntityID)
if rows IsNot Nothing Then
   For x = 0 to rows.Length - 1
      InlineAssignHelper(rows(x), "DisplayOrder", x+1))
      ' At this point you can also directly set the column without an helper function
      ' rows(x)("DisplayOrder") = x+1
   Next
End If

Public Sub InlineAssignHelper(row As DataRow, colName as String, value As Integer)
     row(colName) = value
End Sub
```